Appending xStream output to an xml file with proper structure
I am writing a small Java program to keep and update a list of books in my personal library. A prompt asks the user for the book's data and the new book is saved (appended) to an XML file. The method below from the Book class is responsible for this:
public void updateBookList(String title, String author, String publisher, int year, int numPages){
        XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
        xstream.alias("book", Book.class);

        Book book = new Book(title, author, publisher, year, numPages);
        String dataXml = xstream.toXML(book);

        try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("booklist.xml", true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
        {
            out.println(dataXml);
        
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // fix later
        }
    }

The idea is that the file serves as a simple persistent storage of sorts, with all my books listed neatly in XML format.
However, after inserting two test books, this is what the XML looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" ?><book><title>Test1</title><author>Test1</author><publisher>Test1</publisher><year>1999</year><numPages>202</numPages><dateCreated>2024-07-17</dateCreated><dateModified>2024-07-17</dateModified></book>
<?xml version="1.0" ?><book><title>Test2</title><author>Test2</author><publisher>Test2</publisher><year>1999</year><numPages>234</numPages><dateCreated>2024-07-17</dateCreated><dateModified>2024-07-17</dateModified></book>

How can I append the data so the XML file looks something like this:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<book>
    <title>Test1</title>
    <author>Test1</author>
    <publisher>Test1</publisher>
    <year>1999</year>
    <numPages>202</numPages>
    <dateCreated>2024-07-17</dateCreated>
    <dateModified>2024-07-17</dateModified>
</book>

<book>
    <title>Test2</title>
    <author>Test2</author>
    <publisher>Test2</publisher>
    <year>1999</year>
    <numPages>234</numPages>
    <dateCreated>2024-07-17</dateCreated>
    <dateModified>2024-07-17</dateModified>
</book>


The issue might be related to appending new books to the XML file without considering the existing structure of the file, meaning, each time you append a new book, you are adding a new XML declaration <?xml version="1.0" ?> and not enclosing all books with a single root element which makes your XML invalid

One idea could be to create a class called Books that contains a List of Book class objects, let's call it bookList. Then when you want to add a new book, create a new Book object and add it to the Books where it will be added to the bookList. Then use XStream to serialize entire Books to XML.

You first need to parse the xml file on disk into a List, add the new book to it and then xtream the List

You're trying to mix two different paradigms. That's not going to work. You can try to kludge it with random access techniques but that's nasty. Your real problem is trying to use XML as a database

I am indeed aware that the XML isn't valid as it is, it is one of the problems I was trying to fix. Also, is there any idea or solution for storage in such a small project? All I want is a persistent record of my books and be able to perform simple CRUD operations, but a database for that seemed a bit of an overkill.

What you are looking for is the ability to "Pretty Print" the XML while also not writing the Prolog. So just Google on how to do that using the XStream parser.

@Julles BTW if all that you actually want to do is simple CRUD on your data and persist the data to a file in XML format, then, do the CRUD in memory and write all the data to a file every time you make a single change. In other words, forget appending, just overwrite everything that is there.

that is basically what I ended up doing, but switched to JSON for practicality, using Jackson to serialize. I removed the updateBookList method and approached it like @Hagelslag suggested by creating a new class to handle updating the list.

a well formed xml document has always one single root node, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element
thus say you need to create a proper model that represents that structure, maybe you collect your books within a Books class
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<books>
  <book>
    ...
  </book>
  <book>
    ...
  </book>
</books>

